# Get Title instead of ID in Wordpress Function

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this function in a wordpress site:

```
    function cf7_get_custom_field($atts){
        extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'key' => '',
            'post_id' => -1,
            'obfuscate' => 'off'
        ), $atts));

        if($post_id < 0){
            global $post;
            if(isset($post)) $post_id = $post->ID;
        }

        if($post_id < 0 || empty($key)) return '';

        $val = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);

        if($obfuscate == 'on'){
    $val = cf7dtx_obfuscate($val);
        }

        return $val;`
```

The return $val gives the **post ID number**, but instead I would like it to be the **post title**.

The line:
               `$val = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);`
Should have get_post_title or get_title in there somewhere, I suppose.

Any tips?

Comment: Would you like to get the post meta with post title not from post id?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) which returns the title of the post based on the post ID number.

```
$val = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, true);
$post_title = get_the_title( $val );

return $post_title;
```

Comment: But what I am trying to do is get the value from $key, witch is the ID a custom field inside the post (a dropbox with names, based on another custom post type)

Comment: Since $val is the post_id, why don't you use it as argument inside `get_the_title` ? Code updated.